# How to check if String is null

Tags: c#, null

I am wondering if there is a special method/trick to check if a `String` object is null. I know about the [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method but I want to differentiate a `null` String from an empty String (=`""`).

Should I simply use:

```
if (s == null) {
    // blah blah...
}
```

...or is there another way?

Comment: @Thilo: I don't. Just to learn the best ways of using C#.

Comment: Actually, it was good that you asked. Seems to be straightforward in C#, but for example in Javascript there are a lot of nuances concerning null checks.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

An *object* can't be null - the value of an *expression* can be null. It's worth making the difference clear in your mind. The value of `s` isn't an object - it's a *reference*, which is either null or refers to an object.

And yes, you should just use

```
if (s == null)
```

Note that this will still use the overloaded == operator defined in string, but that will do the right thing.

Comment: @Thilo: No, I doubt it. The == implementation would have to be broken for that to help, and the calling code becomes uglier.

Comment: @Thilo: I would prefer not to work with broken code at all, rather than working with an == implementation which worked if the first argument is null but not the second. Who's to say it wouldn't be changed to work the other way round? Note that assuming a symmetric declaration, the same overload will still be called either way.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the null coalescing double question marks to test for nulls in a string or other nullable value type:

```
textBox1.Text = s ?? "Is null";
```

The operator '??' asks if the value of 's' is null and if not it returns 's'; if it is null it returns the value on the right of the operator.

More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

And also worth noting there's a null-conditional operator ?. and ?[ introduced in C# 6.0 (and VB) in VS2015

```
textBox1.Text = customer?.orders?[0].description ?? "n/a";
```

This returns "n/a" if description is null, or if the order is null, or if the customer is null, else it returns the value of description.

More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: This is one of those answers that probably isn't the exact answer the author was looking for, but it definitely complements my coding skills in c#. I always enjoy reading the other  answers to find more than what I was looking for.

Answer (score 32):

To be sure, you should use a function to check for null and empty as below:

```
string str = ...
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
...
}
```

Comment: The author wants to check exactly for null (not null or empty).

Comment: Great answer if somebody wants to check for both null and empty values, but that is not what the question ask here.

Comment: Perhaps the author wanted to take a different code path in case the string was empty (and not null).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `C# 7.0` or above you can use `is null`:

```
if (s is null) {
    // blah blah...
}
```

Also, note that when working with strings you might consider also using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` that will also validate that the string doesn't contain only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For .net 5 (probably also for .net Core 3.1)

Different possibility to write but always the same problem.

```
string wep = test ?? "replace";
Console.WriteLine(wep);
```

result: "replace"

or

```
string test=null;
test ??= "replace";
Console.WriteLine(test);
test="";
test??="replace";
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

- first try: "replace"
- second try: blank

```
string test="";
if(test is null)
    Console.WriteLine("yaouh");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not yahouu");
```

Result: "Not yahou"

Comment: This is also possible for .NET Framework. `object is null` is available since C# 7 specification.