# Best C# method for checking for a null string value

Tags: c#, string, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if String is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553567/how-to-check-if-string-is-null)

I need to be able to check for a `null` value, only, inside a string. The best method I am currently aware of is `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`, which does not fit what we are trying to do (`string.empty` values are allowed, `nulls` are not). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you should check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553567/how-to-check-if-string-is-null

Comment: why not use the IsNullOrEmpty check..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: OP has explained that, because `String.Empty` is ok whereas `null` is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just compare your string to `null`

```
bool stringIsNull = mystring == null;
```

---

here's an extension method for you

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsNull(this string str)
    {
        return str == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this throw an error if mystring actually is null?

Comment: @NealR No, it won't, it will just return `true`.

Comment: @NealR No, it's evaluating `mystring == null` and then setting `stringIsNull` to that value. To make it more explicit: `bool stringIsNull = (mystring == null)`

Comment: @NealR Extension methods are really just static methods. So in the case of this extension method: `string a = null; a.IsNull() // true - no exception thrown` is just really doing `string a = null; ExtensionMethods.IsNull(a)`

Answer (score 5):

You check the same way you check if any other variable is null:

```
if(variable == null)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to skip `null` values, simply use `!= null`:

```
if(str != null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (variable != null) 
 //do your action for not null
else 
  //variable is null
```